# Compiling the kernel of Beaglebone black

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I followed the procedures to compile the kernel for beaglebone black
git clone git://github.com/beagleboard/kernel.git

```
cd kernel
git checkout 3.8
./patch.sh
cp configs/beaglebone kernel/arch/arm/configs/beaglebone_defconfig
wget http://arago-project.org/git/projects/?p=am33x-cm3.git\;a=blob_plain\;f=bin/am335x-pm-firmware.bin\;hb=HEAD -O kernel/firmware/am335x-pm-firmware.bin
cd kernel
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- beaglebone_defconfig -j4
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage dtbs LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
```

when i try to compile  this step:

`$make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4`, i got the following error:

make: *** No rule to make target `uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack'.  Stop.

without this uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack file i'm not able to boot the image from board

if any one faced such issues ..help to resolve this resolve

Comment: Try putting only `uImage` in the make target instead of `uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack` and once the `uImage` is obtained, rename it to `uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the results of the "patch.sh" script. It is possible that the patch.sh script failed because you did not have the git user.email configuration set.  Here was the error I received:

```
Switched to a new branch 'tmp-patching-branch-sha'
v3.8.13
/home/tkawamura/Development/kernel/patches/dma/0001-Without-MACH_-option-Early-printk-DEBUG_LL.patch:
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'tkawamura@kawamura-ubuntu.(none)')
You need to set your committer info first
```

I was able to set my user.email and rerun patch.sh. Once completed, my compile of uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack was successful.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
    $make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage-dtb.am335x-boneblack LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
```

change it to

```
    $make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage am335x-boneblack.dtb LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
```

it will get compiled